# Generate low rank tensor

Tags: matlab, tensor

In MATLAB, I need to generate a tensor X of size e.g. 13x10x80 with ranks (4,3,15), i.e., the first, second and third foldings have ranks 4, 3, and 15, respectively.

How can I do this in MATLAB?

Comment: It seems rather a mathematical question, therefore it may be useful to ask it https://math.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: You can use the "tensor toolbox" in matlab to do this.

Answer (score 0):

As 'kmario23' mentioned you can use  [Matalb tensor toolbox](http://www.sandia.gov/~tgkolda/TensorToolbox/index-2.6.html) to do this. I think this is what you are looking for:

```
X = tenrand([13 10 80]) %<-- Generate data
U1 = nvecs(X,1,4); %<-- Mode 1
U2 = nvecs(X,2,3); %<-- Mode 2
U3 = nvecs(X,3,15); %<-- Mode 3
S = ttm(X,{pinv(U1),pinv(U2),pinv(U3)}); %<-- Core
Y = ttensor(S,{U1,U2,U3});
```